# Operate with number in excel cell, which has number and text

Tags: python, excel

I am having a trouble with code below.

**Firstly**, I am trying to replace symbol "," with "." because I want to have "," everywhere instead "." but it does not affect the change in excel cells.

**Second**, I am trying to convert grams to kilograms in excel column. Empty space is cell with no information. Look at dots too. They have to get up commas.

```
Current column:
140 g
2.68 kg
3,52 kg
5.7 kg
12,45 kg
360 g
350 g
129 g
75 g
0,095 kg
98,6 g


33 g
395 g
470 g
557 g
1.416 kg
2,021 kg
```

====================

```
Excepted result:
0,14 kg
2,68 kg
3,52 kg
5,7 kg
12,45 kg
0,36 kg
0,35 kg
0,129 kg
0,075 kg
0,095 kg

0,033 kg
0,395 kg
0,47 kg
0,557 kg
1,416 kg
2,021 kg
0,0986 kg
```

====================

**Last working update at 10.04.2022** (For better solutions, write comment)

```
import openpyxl


def converter(excel_path):
    inv_file = openpyxl.load_workbook(excel_path)
    product_list = inv_file.active

    for row in range(2, product_list.max_row + 1):
        weights = product_list.cell(row, 18).value  # column number

        if weights is None:
            print("Empty cell")
        else:
            for value in weights.split():
                if value == "g":
                    try:
                        new_value = str(weights[:-1])  # I am removing "g" at end, to calculate without string
                        conversion = float(new_value) / 1000
                        new_weight = (str(conversion) + " kg")
                        weights = new_weight.replace(".", ",")
                        product_list.cell(row, 18).value = weights
                    except:
                        print("Invalid value")
                else:
                    weights = weights.replace(".", ",")
                    product_list.cell(row, 18).value = weights

            print(weights)

    inv_file.save("converted_table_export.xlsx")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    converter("convert_table.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed the Excel code so I can help with the conversion. I just made a list of the three examples you provided. Review my code and update your code accordingly. UPDATE: I corrected one of the lines below as discussed in the comments below.

```
weights = ["140 g", "2,68 kg",""]

for weight in weights:

    if weight == "":
        print("Weight: empty")
    else:
        # replace a , in cell with .
        weight = weight.replace(",", ".")

        text_separator = weight.split()

        # [0] is for getting number
        # [1] is for "g" or "kg"
        if text_separator[1] == "g":
            new_value = (str(float(text_separator[0]) / 1000)+" kg").replace(".",",")
        else:
            new_value = weight
        print("Weight: {}  New Weight: {}".format(weight,new_value))
```

Output:

```
Weight: 140 g  New Weight: 0,14 kg
Weight: 2,68 kg  New Weight: 2,68 kg
Weight: empty
```

Comment: I updated code in first comment. I tried your code and I am receiving the same problem as first time:

if text_separator[1] == "g":

IndexError: list index out of range

PS: that is my column with described weights

weights = str(product_list.cell(row, 18).value)

Comment: You are getting that if you didnot add code to check for empty cells.  If cell is empty, you will not have text_sapartor[1].

Comment: I updated code. Okay, I avoid the error, but now it is understanding every cell except empty cell as grams: "2.68 kg | This value is in grams. Has to be converted". You can see that it is in "kg". And also changing "," to "." is not working too.

Comment: Your example in your post did state any of the issue you discuss. You need to add more examples so I can understand what's going on.

Comment: I updated completely first post and posted more examples for clarity. I hope you will understand what I am trying to do. Please, check it.

Comment: Update. Almost done. I am receiving this error: ValueError: could not convert string to float: '98,6 ' and cannot finish exporting my file. Do you have how can I fix this?

Comment: I had a mistake. update the line with replace() to look like `weight = weight.replace(",", ".")`

Comment: There is another problem at run: if text_separator[1] == "g":
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: You are probably not checking for the empty cells properly.

Comment: If you are right, I wouldnt receive messages for "Empty cell".

Comment: Last update at 10.04.2022. I modified code. The code works perfectly and executes every single function I wanted. Thank you for help! I appreciate it.

Comment: With pleasure, but I am newbie and dont have 15 reputation points to give you a vote. Sorry.